# Realm Xamarin.Android Unit Test System.PlatformNotSupportedException

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, realm

I'm trying to unit tests my Realm (1.1.0) implementation using a Xamarin.Android Unit Test project since I cannot unit test a PCL library.

When I invoke

```
_realm = Realm.GetInstance();
```

I get the following error:

```
Fail [FAIL] : System.PlatformNotSupportedException : The PCL build of Realm is being linked which probably means you need to use NuGet or otherwise link a platform-specific Realm.dll to your main application.
          at Realms.RealmPCLHelpers.ThrowProxyShouldNeverBeUsed () [0x00000] in <a0bdda658c634b1e932b3ea414073102>:0 
          at Realms.Realm.GetInstance (Realms.RealmConfigurationBase config) [0x00000] in <a0bdda658c634b1e932b3ea414073102>:0 
          at DrifterApps.FeedTheHole.Core.Realms.TestRealmQueries.Setup () [0x00003] in /Users/patrick/Projects/FeedTheHole/Core.Realms.Tests/Realms/TestRealmQueries.cs:17 
          at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
          at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305 
    Ignore [INFO] : another time
```

My project includes the Realm library as such:

```
<Reference Include="Remotion.Linq">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Remotion.Linq.2.1.1\lib\portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80\Remotion.Linq.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Realm">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Realm.Database.1.1.0\lib\MonoAndroid44\Realm.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Realm.Sync">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Realm.1.1.0\lib\MonoAndroid44\Realm.Sync.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DotNetCross.Memory.Unsafe">
  <HintPath>..\packages\DotNetCross.Memory.Unsafe.0.2.3.4\lib\netstandard1.0\DotNetCross.Memory.Unsafe.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

The Realm team fixed the issue with release 1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Update 2023. Now realm has InMemoryConfiguration. Use it like:

```
var config = new InMemoryConfiguration("my-identifier");
var realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);
```